# Assigning an Int pointer to a double variable

Tags: c++, pointers, casting

I want to have an Int pointer point to a double but am recieving the following error: "cannot convert 'double*' to 'int*' in assignment"

Say we have:

```
double myVar1; 
int *myPointer1 = new int; 

myPointer = &myVar1; (cannot convert 'double*' to 'int*' in assignment error)
```

How do I fix my code? I can't make the pointer a "double" because this is for a school assignment and I was specifically asked to use these data types.

Comment: Are you sure that's what you're supposed to do with your assignment?

Comment: 1) You can't do that. 2) Your code contains a memory leak (`new` without corresponding `delete`, and the pointer returned by `new` is lost).

Comment: I am not sure, this wouldn't be the first time there was a typo in a homework assignment. To complete the assignment I just made the pointer a double. In my code I did have the corresponding delete.

Answer (score 2):

You can write:

```
int *myPointer1 = reinterpret_cast<int *>(&myVar1);
```

However it will be [undefined behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4105123/1505939) to use this pointer to try and access the `double`. So there is not really any reason to write this code.